# How to scanf 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I'm currently trying to scan two ints into an array, it works, until I input the two numbers and the program crashes. Where am I wrong here?

```
int teamWins = 0, opponentWins = 0, i = 0, gameNums = 0;
int games[1][100];  

printf("Enter Number of Games for Input: ");
    scanf("%d", &gameNums);

    for (i = 0; i <= gameNums; i++) {
        printf("Input the scores (Team vs. Opponent (ex. 10 5)): ");
            scanf("%d %d", &games[1][100]);
    }

    printf("%d %d", games[1][100]);

    return gameNums;
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do?  `scanf("%d %d", &games[1][100]);`  What are your compiler warnings telling you?

Comment: What I expect it to do is input my numbers to [0][0], [0][1]......[1][0], [1][1] and so on.

Comment: Read a book. Don't try to guess the codes.

Comment: With `int games[1][100];`, code can access the 2D array with `games[a][b];`.  `b` must be in the range [0 ... 99].  `a` must be in the range [0 ... 0].  `games[1][100]` is no good.

Answer (score 5):

```
int games[1][100];
```

declares a two dimensional array of `int` with size=1 in the first dimension and size=100 in the second dimension.  The only valid index in the first dimension is `0` and the valid indices in the second dimension are `0-99`.

Now check the following statement:

```
scanf("%d %d", &games[1][100]);
```

There are two problems here, both of which are undefined behavior.

1) This statement attempts to read two integers from standard input but only provides one destination

According to the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p2): (Thank you @DavidBowling for the reference)

> The fscanf function reads input from the stream pointed to by stream,
>   under control of the string pointed to by format that specifies the
>   admissible input sequences and how they are to be converted for
>   assignment, using subsequent arguments as pointers to the objects to
>   receive the converted input. **If there are insufficient arguments for
>   the format, the behavior is undefined.**

2) The value at value at `games[1][100]` is already outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I'm not sure where your quote came from, but it would be good to provide a citation. [Here is a link to the relevant part of the C11 Draft Standard, §7.21.6.2/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p2)

Comment: And 3) even if it weren't out of bounds: `games[1][100]` is an `int`, not a pointer to `int`.

Comment: @Pablo -- `games[1][100]` may be an `int` in theory, but the attempted access causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes I know, that's why I said *even if it weren't out of bounds*. `scanf` is expecting a pointer to `int`, not an `int`.

Comment: OP code _does_ use `&games[1][100]`; my point was that the expression `games[1][100]` evaluates to an `int` _in theory_, but may not actually evaluate to an `int`, given the UB.

Comment: @DavidBowling ok, I get what you were trying to say.

Comment: @Pablo -- a little bit I was engaging in useless hair-splitting. If `games[1][100]` were in bounds (as you were suggesting), then it would evaluate to an `int`.

Comment: I wonder if there is any benefit in using `games[1][100]` instead of just `games[100]`; both have 100 elements, right?

Comment: @J...S I would guess OP meant to have `int games[2][100]`

Answer (score 0):

To scan a 2d array use must use two for loops with two control variable like "i","j".

```
 for( i=0;i<gameNums;i++)
    for(j=0;j<gameNums;j++)
           scanf("%d",& games [i][j]);
```

Use like this to get output. This is an sample code.
 I can't understand your objective of your code . So edit your question to get full answer.